# How to rebind tinyMCE editor to a moved dom element?

Tags: javascript, dom, tinymce-4

I list the tinyMCE plugin under a structure like so:

```
Email-Workspace
 module-container
  email-contact-ui
   inner-container
    email-body-section
    email-editor
     mceu_12
      mceu_12-body
```

A user event shifts the module-container element to another location

```
New-Workspace
module-container
 email-contact-ui
  inner-container
   email-body-section
    email-editor
```

However under the email-editor tinyMCE no longer appears to be bound to that new DOM location.

```
What I see:
* tinyMCE.editors.length --> 1
* tinyMCE.editors[0].getBody() --> shows correct body text

I've tried: 
* destroying editor and reinit, 
* I've tried this with .destroy, remove, tinyMCE.EditorManager.execCommand 'mceRemoveEditor' and 'mceAddEditor', true.
```

None of these seem to rebind to that existing DOM element?

Any other ideas to try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I solved this by writing a destroyEditor function, which set the editor to null and that allowed me to rebind it in the new location. Then it was a matter of setting the rebind to the last possible event, to ensure all the DOM was in place and any changes are made. Also need to check for making too many editors. I did try many of the suggestions I found online, but none of those seemed to work for my situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you manipulate the DOM underneath TinyMCE you need to

1. Remove the editor from the textarea (before any DOM manipulation happens)
2. Perform DOM manipulation
3. Init editor on new DOM element (at new location)

If that is not working I would make a simple TinyMCE Fiddle or JS Fiddle that shows running code so people can help you determine why its failing.